# Validar bootstrap wizard al hacer clic en el botón "Siguiente"

Tags: javascript, html, c#, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Actualmente estoy usando bootstrap wizard con barra progresiva de este [template](https://themesbrand.com/minia/layouts/form-wizard.html) para crear un formulario por pasos:

```
    @model MyProject.ViewModels.Test.TestViewModel
    <form asp-controller="Test" asp-action="Create" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" class="needs-validation" role="form" novalidate>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="twitter-bs-wizard-nav nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#progress-station-profile" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="step-icon" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Station Profile">
                    <i class="bx bxs-user-detail"></i>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="progress-station-profile">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="CallLetters" class="form-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="CallLetters" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Call Letters is required.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="Market" class="form-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Market" class="form-control" required autofocus/>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Market is required.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="Format" class="form-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="Format" class="form-select" required>
                        <option value="Test 1">Test 1</option>
                        <option value="Test 2">Test 2</option>
                        <option value="Test 3">Test 3</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">Format is required.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label asp-for="Frequency" class="form-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Frequency" class="form-control" autofocus/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="pager wizard twitter-bs-wizard-pager-link">
            <li class="next">
                <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Siguiente
                    <i
                        class="bx bx-chevron-right ms-1">
                    </i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
     ..///proximo paso etc..
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary me-1" value="Save"/>
    </form>
```

Como puede ver, algunos de mis campos son obligatorios, y quiero lograr validar esos campos a través de la validación del lado del cliente cuando el usuario hace clic en el botón "Siguiente". Lo que pasa actualmente es que valida al final del formulario (botón de enviar), y el usuario no tiene idea de qué paso fue incorrecto. Por lo tanto, quiero correr las validaciones en cada paso cuando el usuario haga clic en el botón "Siguiente".

**Actualización**

Utilizo validaciones customizables las cuales se muestran en los campos de tal forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay forma de utilizar estas sin las de html default?

Comment: Te refieres a la validación HTML5?? o a la validación de ASP del lado del cliente?

Comment: Como bien dice @Yussef no entiendo bien a cual te refieres, si es el caso de que te refieres a la parte html5 o visual. Puedes usar pattern y si no cumple los requisitos le saltara un mensajito diciendo xq es invalido, tambien puedes usar css con pseudoclass como invalid: para darle color o algo que haga si es invalido, correcto o requierido. Por lo demas diria que aclarases o bien con imagenes el resultado que quieres o de otra manera mas entendible o expresiva

Comment: Sí, me refiero a la validación HTML5 @Yussef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las validaciones HTML5 tienen 2 funciones importantes

- checkValidity: Retorna true o false
- reportValidity: Muestra la validación visualmente

Un Wizard debería tener la siguiente estructura:

```
form
  ventana1
    inputs
    botón next
  ventana2
    inputs
    botón next
  submit
```

Entonces la logía debería ser que al momento de presionar el botón next, mostrara la validación, y si hay algún dato incorrecto no pasara a la siguiente ventana

Para esto hay que evaluar todos los inputs, select y textareas que contiene la ventana (solo la ventana en cuestión)

Demo:

```js
function validar(ventana){
  let v = document.getElementById(ventana); //obtenemos la ventana contenedora
  //buscamos todos los inputs y select de la ventana contenedora
  v.querySelectorAll("input,select,textarea").forEach(e=>{
    if(!e.checkValidity()){
      //e.reportValidity(); // para validación html5
      e.classList.toggle("is-invalid"); //para validación boostrap
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      return false;
    }
    else{
      e.classList.toggle("is-invalid");//para validación boostrap
    }
  });
  return true;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form novalidate>
  <div id="ventana1" class="ventana">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Call Letters is required.</div>
    <button type="button" onclick="return validar('ventana1')">Validar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Dejé comentado 2 líneas event.PreventDefault() y event.stopPropagation(), desconozco el funcionamiento del wizard que estas ocupando, si al presionar next sigues pasando a la siguiente ventana, deberás descomentar esas líneas.

Comment: @Demian no es `e` es `event`, favor vuelve a probar y me avisas

Comment: Funciona!, una última pregunta, hay posibilidad de ejecutar las custom validations que tengo? como puedes ver, debajo de cada input tengo una validación cuando tienen el html tag `required` pongo el input rojo `<div class="invalid-feedback">Call Letters is required.</div>`, se puede ejecutar en lugar de lanzar la de puro html5? Agrego imágen en pregunta de cómo se ve este tipo de validación

Comment: Es bootstrap  versión 5

Comment: @Demian Ahí está, recuerda dejar la respuesta como aceptada si te ha parecido de ayuda. Saludos y suerte